# Apictl 403 forbidden on creating new API

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I get the following error when trying to create a new API:

```
PS C:\apictl> .\apictl init PetstoreAPI --oas https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.2.0/assets/attachments/get_started/petstore.json
Initializing a new WSO2 API Manager project in C:\apictl\PetstoreAPI
apictl: Error initializing project Reason: could not access document at "https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.2.0/assets/attachments/get_started/petstore.json" **[403 Forbidden]**
Removing the project directory C:\apictl\PetstoreAPI with its content
```

Can somebody help me please?

I tried to:

- deactivate Windows firewall
- changed to http instead of https in the url
- My Api manager is still active
- calling the json from browser works correctly (i see the content of json file)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are following WSO2 Documentation. I encountered the same error.Don't know the reason. But for now you can use the following command to continue.

```html
 ./apictl init PetstoreAPI --oas https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json
```